# $_SESSION variable rewritten

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm having a really weird behavior with php's session variables.

The problem is that the session value is being rewritten automatically with no apparent reason.

Code snippet illustrating is something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = 5;
echo $_SESSION["id"]; // Echoes 5
$id = $_REQUEST["id"]; // Being for example $_REQUEST["id"] = 3
echo $_SESSION["id"]; // Echoes 3

?>
```

May it be something misconfigured?

P.S.: Running PHP version is 5.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `register_globals` set to on in your php.ini configuration.  That means you can reference `$_SESSION['id']` just using the variable `$id`, leading to the problem you're seeing in your example above.  Set `register_globals` to off in php.ini and try again.

Comment: Thanks, really easy solution! Problem nº 2 is that client _needs_ to use the program on a shared hosting with no possibility of change any php variable. So I select this as accepted answer, but unfortunately can't resolve my problem

Comment: Try adding the following to an .htaccess file: php_flag register_globals 0

Comment: Can't... One of the cons of almost free shared hostings... If the client wants an update I'll fix disabling `register_globals` on php.ini, with ini_set() or in the .htaccess file. Thanks anyway